# switch to a Full Screen application with keybind

Tags: shortcut, window-manager, keybindings

I use a lot of Spaces and I switch between them using keybinds (from `cmd + 1` to access the first space, to `cmd + 5` to access the last one).

I'd like to switch to a Full Screen application using the method described above, but because this mode creates a new workspace, mixing up a Window and a Space (like a *Windospace*), I can't.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Ex: Say I want the Full Screen Firefox application to always be reachable with `cmd + 6` and not only `cmd + TabTabTabTabTaaaaaaaabTab`.